# changing properties of elements of a class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the properties of the 'im' and 'desc' class within 'img' class.I am passing the current element to the javascript functions mOver() and mDown().When I mouseover the border of the image as well as the text underneath it should change.Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.img
    {
    margin:2px;
    border:1px solid #0000ff;
    height:90;
    width:110;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    }
.im
    {
    width:110px;
    height:90px;
    display:inline;
    margin:3px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    }
.desc
    {
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:normal;
    width:120px;
    margin:2px;
    }
</style>
<script>
function mOver(a)
    {
    a.style.border="10px solid #0000ff";
    a.getElementByClassName("desc").innerHTML="Click on the image";
    }
function mDown(a)
    {
    a.style.border="1px solid #ffffff";
    a.getElementByClassName("desc").innerHTML="You have clicked already";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mDown(this)">
    <a target="_blank" href="abc.png">
    <img class="im" src="abc.png"></a>
    <div class="desc">ABC</div>
</div>
<div class="img" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mDown(this)">
    <a target="_ blank" href="def.png">
    <img class="im" src="def.png"></a>
    <div class="desc">DEF</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The text underneath the image isn't changing as it should have to.
I think the is something wrong with the line

```
a.getElementByClassName("desc").innerHTML="You have clicked already";
```

I am relatively new to javascript so please let me know what is wrong here.Anyways thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be `getElementsByClassName` (plural) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `getElementsByClassName` with an "s". And you're also supposed to mark the index of the element whose `innerHTML` you want to change. If you wanted to change the first element, do this:

```
a.getElementsByClassName("desc")[0].innerHTML = "You have clicked already";
```

Since arrays are 0-indexed, this changes the first element in the array returned by the method.

But if you were intending to change all the elements with that class name then you must loop:

```
var elements = a.getElementsByClassName("desc");

for (var i = elements.length; i--;) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "You have clicked already";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you are trying to use is called `getElementsByClassName` (it expects multiple elements to be found as opposed to `getElementById`) and returns a Node List. Your line should therefore read:

```
a.getElementsByClassName("desc")[0].innerHTML="You have clicked already";
```

For documentation read **[MDN on NodeLists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList)**